# Best practice to install background image

Tags: android

I have jpeg image which should be installed on background of layout (full screen). I guess I should measure device screen height and width and zoom my picture. I also got onClick freezes when tried center crop picture in xml. Any recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Here is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark"
    android:background="#1B1B21">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/above_mountains"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/above_mountains"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="48dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    ...ACTUAL LAYOUT HERE...

</LinearLayout> 

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:background="@drawable/your_image.jpg"` on your layout?

Comment: So you wanna know 'how to install a jpeg on a background of an app' and 'how to prevent freezes on click while trying to crop picture'? If yes, you need to post your code for 2nd one. Question is not clear btw, you need to clarify it.

Comment: I added my layout. I need to zoom with crop & no freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `Glide` image loading library

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.above_mountains).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Comment: Is it better than Picasso? Center crop isn't a good decision. I need to zoom with crop.

Comment: Yes, check [documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). `CenterCrop` automatically zooming with crop

Comment: Thanks. Sounds pretty sweet. I'll try it. If all will be ok, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Do I need to free memory onDestroy?

Comment: @Daimonium No, Glide automatically handle all of things to provide best performance such as resize image to `ImageView` size to save memory and compatible with `Activity` life cycle and release memory and many more

Comment: Thanks for answer.